# Не могу при помощи css изменить расположение изображений

Tags: html, css, css3

Не могу при помощи CSS изменить расположение изображений.
Должен выглядеть вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но я не могу сделать отступы между ними.

Прообую так ([на codepen](https://codepen.io/Maref/pen/ExaaZGw)):

```css
.bg5
{
 background-color: #ffdd99;
 height: 1423px;
}
.s5_head
{
 max-width: 540px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
.s5_title
{
 padding-top: 115px;
 color: #393939;
 font-size: 40px;
 font-weight: 700;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 text-align: center;
 letter-spacing: 4px;
 line-height: 30px;
 margin-bottom: 16px;
}
.s5_line
{
 border:none;
 background-color: #e5c37f;
 width:75px;
 height:4px;
 margin-bottom: 16px;
}
.s5_head_text
{
 text-align: center;
 color: #393939;
 font-size:18px;
 font-weight: 400;
 letter-spacing: 0.36px;
 line-height: 26px;
}
.s5_menu
{
 margin-top: 55px;
 text-align: center;
}
.s5_menu_paragraph
{
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #393939;
 font-size: 18px;
 font-weight: 400;
 letter-spacing: 0.36px;
 line-height: 20px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 background-color: #ebc985;
 padding: 6px 24px;
 border-radius:5px;
 text-align: center;
 margin-left: 10px;
 cursor: pointer;
 transition: 0.2s linear;
}
.s5_menu_paragraph:hover
{
 background-color: #fff;
}
.s5_body
{
 margin-top: 70px;
 display:flex;
 flex-wrap:wrap;
}

}
.s5_imgs
{
 margin-left: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.s5_img
{
 height: 310px;
 width: 542px;
}
.s5_under_img_text
{
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Cuda</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web:300,400,600,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
 <section class="bg5">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="s5_head">
    <h1 class="s5_title">
     OUR PORTFOLIO
    </h1>
    <hr class="s5_line">
    <p class="s5_head_text">
     Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam
    </p>
    <nav class="s5_menu">
     <a class="s5_menu_paragraph">
      ALL
     </a>
     <a class="s5_menu_paragraph">
      WEB
     </a>
     <a class="s5_menu_paragraph">
      APPS
     </a>
     <a class="s5_menu_paragraph">
      ICONS
     </a>
    </nav>
   </div>
   <div class="s5_body">
    <div class="s5_imgs">
     <img src="https://i.ibb.co/94gV4wv/computer1.png" alt="computer1" class="s5_img">
     <p class="s5_under_img_text">
      Isometric Perspective Mock-Up
     </p>
    </div>
    <div class="s5_imgs">
     <img src="https://i.ibb.co/VLqKGG1/computer2.png" alt="computer2" class="s5_img">
     <p class="s5_under_img_text">
      Time Zone App UI
     </p>
    </div>
    <div class="s5_imgs">
     <img src="https://i.ibb.co/PMnyVtW/computer3.png" alt="computer3" class="s5_img">
     <p class="s5_under_img_text">
      Viro Media Players UI
     </p>
    </div>
    <div class="s5_imgs">
     <img src="https://i.ibb.co/Qr4fqcZ/computer4.png" alt="computer4" class="s5_img">
     <p class="s5_under_img_text">
      Blog / Magazine Flat UI Kit
     </p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </section>
 </body>
```

Comment: Вот код: https://codepen.io/Maref/pen/ExaaZGw

Comment: а задача-то какая? как должно быть?

Comment: Вставьте код в сообщение, сформулируйте вопрос - так участникам будет более понятно как вам помочь. Старайтесь формулировать к, как будто этот вопрос задают вам.

Comment: flex-box: в помощь flex-flow:

Comment: Исправил вопрос

Comment: Используйте свойство [`gap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gap)

Comment: Не помогло, есть ещё варианты?

Comment: _Но я не могу сделать отступы между ними_ - не совсем понятно, разве между изображениями нет отступов? Поясните [в вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1053924/edit), не в комментарии.

Comment: Изображение это то как оно должно выглядеть, а как оно выглядит сейчас можете посмотреть по первому комментарию, я там ссылку оставил на код

Comment: @Maref Извините конечно, но как вы поняли фразу - _Поясните в вопросе, не в комментарии._?

Answer (score 1):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.bg5 {
  background-color: #ffdd99;
  height: 1423px;
}

.s5_head {
  max-width: 540px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.s5_title {
  padding-top: 115px;
  color: #393939;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  line-height: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}

.s5_line {
  border: none;
  background-color: #e5c37f;
  width: 75px;
  height: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}

.s5_head_text {
  text-align: center;
  color: #393939;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: 0.36px;
  line-height: 26px;
}

.s5_menu {
  margin-top: 55px;
  text-align: center;
}

.s5_menu_paragraph {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #393939;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: 0.36px;
  line-height: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-color: #ebc985;
  padding: 6px 24px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.2s linear;
}

.s5_menu_paragraph:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.s5_body {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 1164px;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 70px;
}

.s5_imgs {
  width: 542px;
  margin: 20px;
}

.s5_img {
  height: 310px;
  width: 542px;
}

.s5_under_img_text {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Cuda</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web:300,400,600,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <section class="bg5">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="s5_head">
        <h1 class="s5_title">
          OUR PORTFOLIO
        </h1>
        <hr class="s5_line">
        <p class="s5_head_text">
          Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam
        </p>
        <nav class="s5_menu">
          <a class="s5_menu_paragraph">
      ALL
     </a>
          <a class="s5_menu_paragraph">
      WEB
     </a>
          <a class="s5_menu_paragraph">
      APPS
     </a>
          <a class="s5_menu_paragraph">
      ICONS
     </a>
        </nav>
      </div>
      <div class="s5_body">
        <div class="s5_imgs">
          <img src="https://i.ibb.co/94gV4wv/computer1.png" alt="computer1" class="s5_img">
          <p class="s5_under_img_text">
            Isometric Perspective Mock-Up
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="s5_imgs">
          <img src="https://i.ibb.co/VLqKGG1/computer2.png" alt="computer2" class="s5_img">
          <p class="s5_under_img_text">
            Time Zone App UI
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="s5_imgs">
          <img src="https://i.ibb.co/PMnyVtW/computer3.png" alt="computer3" class="s5_img">
          <p class="s5_under_img_text">
            Viro Media Players UI
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="s5_imgs">
          <img src="https://i.ibb.co/Qr4fqcZ/computer4.png" alt="computer4" class="s5_img">
          <p class="s5_under_img_text">
            Blog / Magazine Flat UI Kit
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>
```